# Two filtration systems form "a unified system". Is this correct?

Tags: phrase-request, translation, terminology

My translation from Russian:

> The filtration and filling process involves the use of two disposable systems: system 1 and system 2. Before being put into operation, the two systems are connected via a specialized connector, forming **a unified system**, and are installed in(at) the equipment.

Does the phrase **unified system** look okay here? Or is the word **unified** suitable only for something less tangible and implying that they are not physically connected, but rather compatible?

Maybe I should just write **united system** instead? The Multitran dictionary offers several options for the original phrase in Russian, "[единая система](https://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E5%E4%E8%ED%E0%FF%20%F1%E8%F1%F2%E5%EC%E0)".

Comment: IMO, unified system sounds better than, say, '_united system_'.

Comment: **unified** is fine. But if you have latitude to simplify:  "... the two systems are joined by a specialized connector and are installed as a unit."

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22installed%20as%20a%20unit%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: I agree that "unified" is fine, but I still have the feeling there is a better way to express the combination of the two systems.  Is this a *serial* combination, where the filtrate first passes through one system then then second system, or does each work on different filtrates in some sort of "parallel" relationship?

Comment: Unified sounds right in this sentence, and more natural than united.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unified works, but it's not really what I would say.

If, for example, these were the only two components in the filtration I would say these form a **complete** filtration system.

If these combine to do filtration as part of a larger system I would say the two components **work together**.  Or I would say they form a **two-stage** filtration system, where the filtrate passes through one then the other.

Or, alternately, I would just describe the completed assembly as a **combined** system of two filtration units, linked by a specialized connector.

There are other possibilities, but it would help to have more complete information on how the **integrated filtration system** (another option) works with the rest of the assembly.